# Java ArrayList Set with 2 elements

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 3 classes. Main, Leerling, Klas.
My question: What should I put in my Klas.class in order to be able to add variable "cijfer" to my ArrayList? So when I print k.toString it will display variables naam and also cijfer.

Main.class:

```
public class Main{   
    public static void main(String[] arg) {     
        Klas k = new Klas("V1Z");     
        Leerling l = new Leerling("Hans");     
        k.voegLeerlingToe(l);     
        l = new Leerling("Jan");     
        k.voegLeerlingToe(l);     
        l = new Leerling("Wim");     
        k.voegLeerlingToe(l);     
        System.out.println(k);     
        k.wijzigCijfer("Hans", 7.6);     
        k.wijzigCijfer("Klaas", 7.6);     
        System.out.println(k.toString());     
        System.out.println("Aantal leerlingen: " + k.aantalLeerlingen());     
    } 
}
```

Klas.class:
    import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class Klas {
    private String klasCode;
    private ArrayList<Leerling> leerlingen;

    public Klas(String kC){
        klasCode = kC;
        leerlingen = new ArrayList<Leerling>(); 
    }

    public void voegLeerlingToe(Leerling nweLeerling){
        leerlingen.add(nweLeerling);
    }

    public void wijzigCijfer(String nm, Double nweCijfer){
        // What should I put here??
    }

    public ArrayList<Leerling> getLeerlingen(){
        return leerlingen;
    }

    public Integer aantalLeerlingen(){
        return leerlingen.size();
    }

    public String toString(){
        String s = "In klas " + klasCode + " zitten de volgende leerlingen:";
        String p = "";
        System.out.println(s);

        for (Leerling l : leerlingen) {
            System.out.println(l);
        }
        return p;
    }

}
```

Leerling.class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Leerling {
    private String naam;
    private Double cijfer;

    public Leerling(String nwNm){
        naam = nwNm;
    }

    public String getNaam(){
        return naam;
    }

    public Double getCijfer(){
        return cijfer;
    }

    public void setCijfer(Double c){
        cijfer = c;
    }

    public String toString(){
        if (cijfer == null){
            cijfer = 0.0;
        }
        String s = naam + " heeft cijfer: " + cijfer;
        return s;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void wijzigCijfer(String nm, Double nweCijfer){
    // Assuming that you want to find by nm, as shown in your demo
    for (Leerling l : leerlingen) {
        if (l.getNaam().equals(nm)) { // or use equalsIgnoreCase
            l.setCijfer(nweCijfer);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that as the list isn't sorted you must fallback to linear search, which is not optimal. But it should work for this exercise :)

Comment: This works only for the first result, Hans. However Jan still shows up at 0.0.

Comment: If you test it with the code shown above, that's logical: you never change Jan's score and by default it's zero. C'mon, you can do better than that, at least try stepping through the code with the debugger and watch the variables change.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this :

```
public void wijzigCijfer(String nm, Double nweCijfer){
    Leerling l = new Leerling(nm);
    l. setCijfer(nweCijfer);
    leerlingen.add(l);
}
```

And you can remove this method `public void voegLeerlingToe` if you don't need it.

Comment: That's a different question, which is not mentioned by OP, so I assume not required.

Comment: IMO that's exactly what is being asked. "wijzigcijfer" means **modify** score, not create a pupil with given score. Have a look at their democode.

Comment: Yes exactly, I need to modify the current name and add the varible "cijfer" to it.

Comment: Then you probably need a `Map` in which you can check if your object with name already exists. If yes , then update `nweCijfer`, or create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

> when I print k.toString it will display variables naam and also
>   cijfer.

You can replace

```
for (Leerling l : leerlingen) {
    System.out.println(l);
}
```

with

```
 for (Leerling l : leerlingen) {
     System.out.println(l.toString());
 }
```

Since the `Leerling` class already has its `Overriden` definition of the `toString()` method, this should do the needful.

Comment: This is not required, because `System.out.println(l);` will anyways call `l.toString()`

Comment: `System.out.println(l);`is exactly the same as `System.out.println(l.toString());`. So basically your suggestion is to add more boilerplate code to make things work?